# Tomcat server not responding

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I run a web server on tomcat 7 with Java 8, the server perform **a lot** of IO operations - mostly DB and HTTP calls, each transaction consumes a generous amount of memory and it serves around 100 concurrents at a given time.
After some time, around 10,000 requests made, but not in particular, the server start hangs, not respond or respond with empty 500 responses.
I see some errors on the logs which I currently trying to solve, but what bugs me is that I can't figure out what eventually causes that - catalina log file does not show a heap space exception, plus I took some memory dumps and it seems like there's always room to grow and garbage to collect, so I decided it is not a memory problem. Then I took thread dumps, I've always seen dozens of threads in WAITING, TIMED_WAITING, PARKING, etc...from what I read it seems like these threads are available to handle incoming work.
It's worth mentioning that all the work is done asynchronously, with no blocking operations and it seems like all the thread pools are available. Even more, I stop the traffic to the server and let it rest for some time, and even then the issue doesn't go away. So I figured it's also not a thread problem.
So...my question is:
Maybe it is a memory issue? Can it be a thread-cpu issue? can it be anything else?